# How can I make LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the shell environment accessible in my pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, shell, pyinstaller

I have the following python script:

```
import os
print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```

When I run this on the command line using:

```
python test.py
```

I get the correct value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the shell.

However, when I create an executable for my script using pyinstaller, I do not get the actual LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Instead, I get the current directory path or some other random file name. I would like to make the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my shell environment available in my pyinstaller executable so that I can execute other scripts which require LD_LIBRARY_PATH to be set.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/2148). It seems that this has just been fixed in pyinstaller. You can [download the latest development version](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-the-latest-version) and give it a try.

Comment: I downloaded pyinstaller from the develop branch and it worked fine! Thanks!